# How to set permission for /dev/kvm?

Tags: android-emulator

Even after properly installing the Pixel 2 device emulator, Android Studio is giving an error that "The user doesn't have permission to use kvm(/dev/kvm).

Changed the permission with the command "chmod u+x /dev/kvm". But that didn't work.The character-device file became executable but still the error persists. Android device emulator refused to open.

Answer (score 4):

Please follow the steps which i used to run it.

```
sudo apt install qemu-kvm
sudo adduser $USER kvm
sudo chown -R $USER /dev/kvm
cd Android/Sdk/emulator
./emulator -avd Pixel_XL_API_28
```